# Existence of nonnegative solution in diophantine linear equations system with non negative coefficents

Tags: diophantine-equations, integer-programming

Given a Diophantine system of linear equations $Ax = b$, where  $A \in \mathbb{N}^{m\times n}$ and $b\in\mathbb{N}^{m}$, is there a method to determine whether there exists a nonnegative solution $x\in\mathbb{N}^{n}$?

Comment: Presumably you mean $A \in \mathbb N^{m \times n}$, $b \in \mathbb N^m$, $x \in \mathbb N^n$.

Comment: Yes, by the decision procedure for Presburger arithmetic (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presburger_arithmetic).

Comment: It is NP-complete (determining if a solution exists can be done by taking all $x$ with coordinates lower than an appropriate upper bound, and testing. Completeness is easily provable). I must tell you however that the feasibility of such systems is usually determined by constraint programming or branch-and-bound, which is not much better than brute search.

Answer (score 1):

Solve the following integer program

$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{minimize} & 0_n^{\top} \mathrm x\\ \text{subject to} & \mathrm A \mathrm x = \mathrm b\\ & \mathrm x \in \mathbb N^n\end{array}$$

where the objective function is zero due to the fact that we are only interested in deciding feasibility.

Comment: One can use [PuLP](https://www.coin-or.org/PuLP/) to solve the integer program.